# Create a save button in winforms

Tags: winforms, powershell

**Goal:**

I am attempting to create a button that would save a file to desktop. The incoming file is fetched with an `Invoke-WebRequest` using the GET method. I want the save button to be in my pop-up window.

**Here is an example:**

**Side note:**

This code is sitting in a `switch` with a variable split three ways.

```
switch (...) {
  p {
    if ($second -match 'RegexMatch') {
      $resource = $second
      $fileResult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://url.com/$resource/file -WebSession $currentsession
      # End API Call
      Write-Host
      Write-Host '------------' -ForegroundColor Green
      Write-Host 'FILE Results' -ForegroundColor Green
      Write-Host '------------' -ForegroundColor Green
       # Create Window
      Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
      $form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form
      $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
      $form.KeyPreview = $true
      $form.Add_KeyDown {
        if ($_.Control -and $_.KeyCode -eq 'F') {
          Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
          $stringToFind = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Please enter your search terms', 'Find')
          $pos = $textBox.Text.IndexOf($stringToFind)

          if ($pos -ne -1) {
            $textBox.SelectionStart = $pos
            $textBox.SelectionLength = $stringToFind.Length
          }
        }
      }
      # Textbox
      $textBox = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
      $textBox.Dock = [Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
      $textBox.ReadOnly =$true
      $textBox.Multiline = $true
      $textBox.ScrollBars = 'Vertical'
      $textBox.Font = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Font -ArgumentList ('Arial',12)
      $textBox.ForeColor = 'White'
      $textBox.Text = $fileResult
      $textBox.BackColor = 'Black'
      $textBox.ShortcutsEnabled = $true
      $Form.Controls.Add($textBox)
        # Button
      $btn = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
      $btn.Text = 'Finish'
      $btn.DialogResult = 'Ok'
      $btn.Dock = 'bottom'
      $form.Controls.Add($btn)
      if ($form.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok') {
        $tb.lines
      }
    } else {
      Write-Host
      Write-Warning -Message 'Please enter a valid FILE ID'
      Write-Host
    }
    break
  }
  ...
}
```

**Purpose:**

I want to add an option for the user to download the file for a closer look in a different application.

**Question:**

How would I begin to create a button utilizing winforms in powershell to save this file to disk?

**Here is what I have tried:**

```
      $BtnSave=New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
      $BtnSave.Text='Save'
      $BtnSave.Dock='bottom'
      $btnSave.DialogResult='Ok'
      $form.Controls.Add($BtnSave)
      $BtnSave.Add_Click({
          $SaveFileDialog = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog'
          if ($SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok')
          {
            $textBox.Text = $SaveFileDialog.FileName
            Write-Information 'File Saved'
          }
      })
```

**New Problem:**

File is not saving to disk still, but the save file dialog does show up on click. In addition, using Switch -OutFile with my Invoke-WebRequest is shooting me an error.

**Error:**

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Missing an argument for parameter 'OutFile'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
```

Comment: winforms in powershell ? Can you elaborate on this

Comment: @GuidoG yes allow me to modify my post

Comment: @GuidoG "I want the save button to be in my pop-up window." Modified title as well. I am trying to add a button to my pop-up window that would allow me to save the file to disk.

Comment: You could 1. add a button where you want 2. use the `Add_Click()` method to handle its click event and 3. use the `-OutFile` switch for `Invoke-WebRequest` to save the downloaded file to disk.

Comment: @sodawillow okay let me give this a shot and i'll give feedback soon.

Comment: @sodawillow I have updated my post with additional information. I am receiving a new error regarding "-Outfile" switch with invoke-webrequest.

Comment: You need to specify the path on disk ([example](https://4sysops.com/archives/use-powershell-to-download-a-file-with-http-https-and-ftp/#download-with-invoke-webrequest)).

Comment: @sodawillow Okay your advice worked great. Thank you. However, I am dealing with a new issue and modified my post. Please suggest if I should make a new post for this or not. Thanks.

Comment: You should make a new question, this is a different issue.

Comment: @sodawillow And you should post an answer to this one ;-)

Comment: @sodawillow Yes please, if you can and we will up-vote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding a button where you want in the form, the `Add_Click()` method will allow you to handle its click event and run any scriptblock you want (when button is clicked).

At this point, the `-OutFile` argument for `Invoke-WebRequest` will help with saving the downloaded file to disk (pass it the desired path to the file).